# UPDATE statement inside IF ELSE in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was wondering if you can use UPDATE statement inside IF ELSE inside INSERT INTO and it looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO about
SELECT a1, b1, c1
FROM post a
WHERE IF(a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id FROM category b), 
        TRUE,
        (UPDATE about c
        SET c.comments = a.comments
        WHERE a.status == 'active')
```

Currently i am getting syntax error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected '(' (Opening parenthesis)

And

> Syntax error: Missing ')' (Closing parenthesis)

So i am pretty sure your cant because of syntax errors, but am i wrong on this?

Comment: Your query won't work.  But a before/after insert trigger might be able to handle your logic.

Comment: Could you just tell us what you want to do? Your SQL statement looks weird~

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an update in the WHERE clause in MySQL. For such problems, all major relational databases, including MySQL, support triggers - which means, you can trigger a DML command after something changes in some table.

So, in this case, when you change (insert/update/delete) something in your table, you can define an DML actionable.

```
delimiter ;;
create trigger test_trigger
before insert ON about
   write your logic for the update here
end ;;
delimiter ;
```